# Могу ли я узнать в каком Activity я нахожусь из Dialog Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Мне нужно в зависимости от Activity, изменять данные в Dialog Fragment. Допустим если я в MainActivity, то в TextViwe(которое в Dialog Fragment) должен быть текст "1". Если в Main2Activity, то в том же TextView что-то другое. Как можно такое сделать и возможно ли вообще ?

Comment: вы можете при вызове диалога из активити посылать в него некоторый идентификатор через setArguments(), для каждой активити свой и по нему определять из какой именно активити диалог был вызван, соответственно изменяя его отображение

Comment: @pavlofff можете навести пример?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант 1.**

Можно в нужной вам активити создать переменную

```
public static boolean mainActivity= false;
```

и менять ее в методах

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mainActivity= true;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mainActivity= false;
}
```

Тогда из Dialog Fragment можете провести проверку

```
if (MainActivity.mainActivity)
```

**Вариант 2.**
Если можете получить activity - getActivity

```
if ( activity instanceof MainActivity) {
    // do something
}
```

**Вариант 3.**
Воспользоваться setArguments для DialogFragment

[Подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15459259/7540461)

Comment: спасибо, помогло